# Quickly switch monitors

Tags: macos, display

I have two monitors set up. About halfway through the working day the sun glare shines on my primary monitor. As a result I have to switch over my windows so my primary monitor faces away from the source of glare.

Is there a way to quickly switch monitor positioning? For example:

```
------------    ------------
|          |    |          |
|     1    |    |     2    |
|          |    |          |
------------    ------------
```

becomes

```
------------    ------------
|          |    |          |
|     2    |    |     1    |
|          |    |          |
------------    ------------
```

while retaining application window layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working om @Tetsujin's idea as I have the 'Displays have separate Spaces' check.

1. Check the 'Displays have separate Spaces'
2. Create at least two spaces  for each monitor.

Monitor 1:

[image]

Monitor 2:

[image]

In this example  **Desktop 1** on monitor 1  and **Desktop 3** on monitor 2   are my main ones.

To swap a desktop space over to another monitor. That desktop space must not be the active one.

So to swap  **Desktop 1** over to Monitor 2,  **Desktop 2** must be the active one first.

You can then Drag **Desktop 1** over to Monitor 2.

The same is for **Desktop 3** on monitor 2 going over to monitor 1.

*Desktop 4** must be the active one first.

You can then drag **Desktop 3** over to monitor 1.

Monitor 1:

[image]

Monitor 2:

[image]

As you can see the desktop space have been swapped and I can now use them on the displays with the windows in place.

Comment: Looks like this would be a good, if a little awkward solution. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any other answers, I'd say 'no'. Even if you swap monitors from left to right in System Prefs > Displays, they retain their 'physical' layout, merely change which way you need to move the mouse to swap over.

Though... a thought - what if you assign each monitor to be a different Space & swap Spaces for each monitor? I can't test as I don't use that method & don't want to break my existing setup just to experiment.

[image]